# Using Mouse.SetPosition for FPS mouse look but takes over mouse for all windows app

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I have a FPS game and using mouse look. I use Mouse.SetPosition to set the mouse position back to center of the game window at every frame. This works great and the mouse look is working very good. The problem is this takes over mouse position for every windows app. If I alt tab to another app, the mouse constantly tries to goto the center of the game window. This seems like very bad behavior. Any idea how to fix this behavior but still allow my mouse look to still work?

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with User32.dll
I was programing an autoclicker to do my homework (AI) simple
And this website helped me alot...

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32556/Auto-Clicker-C